# How to embed Images in a powershell email using MailMessage

Tags: html, powershell-2.0

I have an email that works from PS. What I have been trying to do is include images embedded in the email (not attachments). Below is what I have so far:

```
function Email
        {   
            $smtpServer = {smtp server}
            $smtpFrom = {email from}
            $smtpTo = {email to}
            $messageSubject = "test"

            $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
            $message.Subject = $messageSubject
            $message.IsBodyHTML = $true
            $credentials=new-object system.net.networkcredential({smtpUsername},{smtpPassword})

             # $message.Body = Get-Content "D:\Program Files\CymbaTech_FBNC_AM\CTDataLoader\data\TestBody.html"

        # The line below will add any attachments you have such as log files.
        $message.Attachments.Add("{path}\Image1.png")
        $message.Body = '<img src="cid:xyz">'

            $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
            $smtp.credentials=$credentials.getcredential($smtpserver,"25","basic")
            $smtp.Send($message)
        }
```

In the above, I have added image tags to the Body.html file. If I open the html directly, it looks as expected with images showing correctly.

When I send the mail however, the images are just displayed as white boxes with a border. Seems that the script is not loading the images in the file.

Has anyone done similar before and have any suggestions?

Comment: they are local files. The html file references them in image tags. I then use the get-content cmdlet to load the html file into the email body.

Comment: did you tried for ***attachments*** with `cid` (_inline images_) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add images as regular attachments. The HTML body must then reference these attachments though the cid attribute: `<img src="cid:xyz">` where "xyz" is the value of the Content-ID MIME attribute on the attachment MIME part.