# HTML embedded image in the email not displayed

Tags: html, powershell, outlook, html-email

This is the first time I am writing power shell scripting, I am trying to automatically send email reports to our users. I am creating outlook object and trying to use it.

```
$Text --> "<br /><font face='Arial'><b><i>For Full Interactive Viewing <a href=http://www.google.com>Click Here</a></i></b></font><br/>"

$MessageImages --> <br/><img src='C:\MyImages\Volume.png'/><br/><br/><hr><br/><img src='C:\MyImages\Value.png'/><br/><br/><hr><br/><hr>

$FinalText = $Text+$MessageImages
```

Now, I am creating the outlook object and sending it.

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

$mail.importance = 2

$mail.subject = “Reports - Automated Email from user list “

$mail.HTMLBody = $FinalText

$mail.SentOnBehalfOfName ="*********"

$mail.To = "*******"

$mail.Send()
```

When I run this script, All images in `$MessageImages` are visible in the email in my computer as the images are present in the location mentioned, but when I send it to someone else, it is showing x mark. I can understand that, it is not able to find the image and so not displaying the embedded image. Can someone help me in solving this?

**Edit** : This is not related to `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` or `Send-Mailmessage`. This is using Outlook object - `New-Object -com Outlook.Application` and so it cannot be considered as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to embedded image in email using Send-Mailmessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223453/unable-to-embedded-image-in-email-using-send-mailmessage). On that question is a link to another duplicate. Have a look at either of those questions to see if you can find your answer. As of now your issue is you are using a local path in the html. You need to be using a relative path and attach the image as an attachment as well

Comment: This is not related to that as they are System.Net.Mail.MailMessage or Send-Mailmessage, but I am using Outlook object here.

Comment: did you tried using `New-Object -com Outlook.Application` ?

Answer (score 0):

If u need to send the HTML report with images in email, u have to attach the images with that email. Refer the below one,

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\MyImages\             
Foreach($file in $files)                   
{                     
$filename = $file.FullName                    
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList  
$filename.ToString()         
$attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True            
$attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"         
$attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpg"             
$attachment.ContentId = $file.ToString()          
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)         
}         
$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)        
$attachment.Dispose();           
$emailMessage.Dispose();
```

In the HTML mention the image source as img src="cid:Volume.png"  and img src='cid:Value.png'

Try it'll works