# Embed image in email using outlook object in powershell

Tags: html, email, powershell, outlook

I already posted a question related to this ([HTML embedded image in the email not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469812/html-embedded-image-in-the-email-not-displayed) ) and updated my script to include cid, but now my images are attached rather than coming inline. I am not sure how I can use inline images in outlook object.

```
$Text --> "<br /><font face='Arial'><b><i>For Full Interactive Viewing <a href=http://www.google.com>Click Here</a></i></b></font><br/>"

$MessageImages --> <br/><img src='cid:Volume.png'/><br/><br/><hr><br/><img src='C:\MyImages\Value.png'/><br/><br/><hr><br/><hr>

$FinalText = $Text+$MessageImages
```

Then I am creating an outlook object and sending it with attachments in it.

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

$mail.importance = 2

$mail.subject = “Reports - Automated Email from user list “

$mail.HTMLBody = $FinalText

$mail.SentOnBehalfOfName ="*********"

$mail.To = "*******"

$mail.Attachments.Add($file.ToString())

$mail.Send()
```

It is attached without any issue, but not embedded inline. Can anyone help on this.

I dont have smtp server details and so I cannot use smtp client. So I tried to use this class System.Net.Mail.Attachment as below, but when I tried to add the attachment as below,

```
PS H:\> $file


    Directory: C:\Users\Images


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-a---       23/09/2015  4:04 p.m.     132361 Volume.png   


 $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList ($file.FullName).ToString() 
 $attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
 $attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
 $attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png"
 $attachment.ContentId = $file.Name.ToString()
 $mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
```

I am getting this error -

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At C:\work\Automated.ps1:130 char:23
+  $mail.Attachments.Add <<<< ($attachment)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Can someone assist me on how to use inline images in outlook object.?

Comment: Why not use [`Send-Mailmessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) instead of messing with a COM API?

Comment: Is it possible to use Send-Mailmessage without smtp server details? I am using local outlook appllication since I dont have smtp server address or name.

Comment: do you use ***attachment*** or ***inline*** (cid) `img src="cid:Volume.png" and img src='cid:Value.png'` ? which is your HTML Body content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property to the matching value of the cid attribute (Volume.png in your case):

```
$attach = $mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "Volume.png")
```

Comment: Do I need to use System.Net.Mail.Attachment to specify the Inline properties or I can directly use PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID ?

Comment: I mean which method to use? This - $mail.Attachments.Add($file.ToString())  or System.Net.Mail.Attachment class ?

Comment: You can use either method, whatever works for you best. My example was for the Outlook Object Model method. If you are using straight MIME with SAMTP, make sure the attachment MIME part has the matching Content-ID MIME header.

Answer (score 0):

Updated and Complete Answer incase if anyone needs :

```
$Text = "<br /><font face='Arial'><b><i>For Full Interactive Viewing <a 
href=http://www.google.com>Click Here</a></i></b></font><br/>"

$MessageImages = "<br/><img src='C:\Users\E5559405\Desktop\IT\Image.jpg'/><br/>"

$FinalText = $Text+$MessageImages

$o = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

$mail.importance = 2

$mail.subject = “Reports - Automated Email from user list “

$mail.HTMLBody = $FinalText

$mail.To = "xyz@gmail.com"

$mail.Send()
```