# Email with inline attachments using powershell

Tags: powershell, email

**Requirement:**

Send a mail with inline image **with out attaching** the image as attachment using powershell.

**My Powershell Code:**

```
$From = "From@gmail.com"
$ToEmails = "ToEmails@gmail.com"
$CcEmails = "CcEmails@gmail.com"
$userName = "From@gmail.com"
$ImageName = "codecover.png"
$FilePath = "D:\$($ImageName)"
$Attachment = @($FilePath)
$Subject = "Test Subject"
$password = "From Email password"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.outlook.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Body += "<img src='$($ImageName)' />"

[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$password = $password
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $securePassword)

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $ToEmails -Cc $CcEmails -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials -Attachments $Attachment –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

**Problem with my Result:**

Result of the mail sending with inline attachment **but the same image is in attachments** which i dont want. Please find the screen shot below

[image]

Please suggest me how to send the inline images without attaching that image in attachments.

Comment: Remove " -Attachments $Attachment" from the Send-MailMessage and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi @BernardMoeskops, if i remove the attachment parameter, the inline image is also not displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed Images in a powershell email using MailMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237687/how-to-embed-images-in-a-powershell-email-using-mailmessage)

Comment: Weird, I tested it from Gmail to Outlook and it worked. Seems it is only not working in Gmail..

Comment: Found it, Google only allows images which are coming from a trusted source. Therefore if you would store the images in for instance Google Drive it works..

Comment: Hi @BernardMoeskops. I'm not using the gmail account i'm using Outlook account only. PLlease see my smtp server which is outlook. I have placed the test gmail addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have it base64 encoded.

```
$Byte    = [system.io.file]::ReadAllBytes("C:\yourImage.png")
$Base64  = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Byte)
$Content = '{0}{1}{2}' -f '<img src="data:image/png;base64,',$Base64,'">'
```

Use the content as the message Body.

Comment: Thank you  for the Answer i think this idea will work. But i have one issue with this. When i send the $Content as my body i'm not getting image in mail. When i check with inspect element i could see like this "<img data-imagetype="Empty" data-imageerror="SrcNullOrEmpty" originalsrc="" src="">". But when i copy pasted the $Content in a web page for checking it is displaing my image perfectly. Can you please suggest why $content is not matched with the image tag in mail. Whether i need to use any content types in mail like. Please suggest

Comment: @Chandramouli I just ran into that "SrcNullOrEmpty" problem today. I changed from PNG to JPEG, which made the file much, much smaller and it worked. PNG (which didn't work) was around 85kB and JPEG was around 7.5kB. I was using other base64 PNG images in the email, which worked, but they were much smaller files. Outlook online clearly messes with the HTML. I wonder if it is just badly coded and has a max length that it can deal with (like 65535 maybe).